# Using web service to update a SharePoint 2010 list from a form located on a public web page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been searching for information on how to do this but haven't found exactly what I'm looking for after a few hours on Google.

I have a form on a public website (old asp unfortunately) that when filled out and submitted, must update a list on a SharePoint 2010 site.

I know that the answer should be in a "lists.asmx" web service, but I'm having a hard time finding a web tutorial on setting this up.

If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am trying to do something similar, and i found this blog post quite useful.

http://sarangasl.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/sharepoint-list-web-service.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for UpdateListItem

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Rob!  Most helpful!